# MySQL: How "overwrite" data in first table if matching id found in second table and ADD whats' missing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similar table:

```
balance_first


+----+---------+
| id | balance |
+----+---------+
|  1 |      12 |
|  2 |      50 |
|  3 |       0 |
|  4 |      55 |
+----+---------+



balance_second

+----+---------+
| id | balance |
+----+---------+
|  2 |     7.5 |
|  4 |    2.33 |
| 10 |    1.23 |
+----+---------+
```

I did try with LEFT JOIN but cannot get my result. And, 'cause final table are about 10k row, I would not use IN clause.

**Final expected result**

id 2 and id 4 are also in balance_second table, so I want move to    balance_first table OVERWRITING balance_first;

id 10 is not present in LEFT table so we add it

Finally id 1 and 3 are only in balance_first, so we need to leave    untouched in final_result

```
+----+---------+
| id | balance |
+----+---------+
|  1 |      12 |
|  2 |     7.5 |
|  3 |       0 |
|  4 |    2.33 |
| 10 |    1.23 |
+----+---------+
```

This is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eabdfe/1

Comment: Because they do part of another, bigger query. I did also simplifiy my issue to the minimum....

Comment: Do you just want to select the data in expected_result, or do you want to update balance_first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get data from `balance2` and use `UNION` to add data from `balance` which is not available in `balance2`.

```
SELECT ID, balance FROM balance2
UNION
SELECT b.ID, b.balance FROM balance b
LEFT JOIN balance2 b2 ON b2.ID = b.ID
WHERE b2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY ID
```

Output:

```
| ID | balance |
|----|---------|
|  1 |      12 |
|  2 |     7.5 |
|  3 |       0 |
|  4 |    2.33 |
| 10 |    1.23 |
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eabdfe/20)

Comment: A combo between UNION and LEFT JOIN. This is perfect. One question, the LEFT join is executed before or after the UNION? Thank you very much, btw

Comment: Inner queries will be executed before UNION.

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea. We could left join 2nd table with first. Then  join 1st table with second. Union both of them to get the results.

```
select id,balance
from ((select b2.id as 'id',b2.balance as 'balance'
from balance2 b2
LEFT JOIN balance b 
ON b2.id = b.id)
UNION
(select b.id as 'id',IF(b2.balance is null,b.balance,b2.balance) as 'balance'
from balance b 
LEFT JOIN balance2 b2
ON b.id = b2.id)) derived_table
order by id;
```